# Getting a value of a record with PouchDB and into local variable for HTML UI usage

Tags: jquery, pouchdb

I am struggling to get a value out of the PouchDB GET call so that I can use it in my HTML during the initial load of the page. I have managed to create the db, and store a record which is easy enough as they dont require me to wait for a return value.

Using the Chrome dev tools I can breakpoint within the PouchDB get call and see that its returning the data I need but its get that value outside of the aysnc GET call that I am having issue with.

The relevant code is as follows (UPDATE for IanC's answer):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    // Store note data as object for pass-by-reference
    var notesData = {note_text:null, note_rev_id:null};

    // Create/get database
    var notesDb = null;

    try {
        notesDb = new PouchDB(notesDbName);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

    // Query for a note entry that has the matching ID
    function pouchDbGetNote(dbId, dbObj, noteObj){
        dbObj.get(dbId)
            .then(function (response) {
                returnNoteData(response, noteObj);
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }

    // Return the result of the GET query to a variable that is is 
    // accessible outside of the aysnc pouchDB GET query.
    function returnNoteData(result, noteObj){
        // Store the note text in local scope - Used in UI display with Div tag
        noteObj.note_text = result.note;

        // Store the note revision id in local scope (Need for updating note in db)
        noteObj.note_rev_id = result._rev;
    }

    /*
    This gets called and debugging thread moves onto lines below
    immediately (notesData is empty at this point) then 'returnNoteData'
    gets called a second time but by this time the UI update calls have occurred.
    */
    pouchDbGetNote(dbEntryId, notesDb, notesData);

    // TODO: Insert the note text into the UI Div, update data attribute on btn with revision id
    notesContentInitialValue = notesData.note_text;
    console.log('msg@ Init - Note: ' + notesData.note_text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

John - you are trying to use **noteResult** before it has been assigned a value. Your code reaches the last two lines before **dbObj.get** Promise resolves.

You have to wait for the Promise to resolve before the value is available. If you moved the last two lines (that assign notesContentInitialValue and noteRevisionId inside the **returnNoteData** function they would have values (as you saw when you debugged it).

Comment: Thanks Ian, that made sense but the issue now is that my `notesdata` object holding the data only gets populated after I try update the UI. Is there a way to trigger the DIV update when I 100% know that my data object has the values needed?

I have updated my code to reflect my most recent changes. Mainly moved code as per your suggestion and now storing variables in a object so I can pass it by reference

Comment: Yes - its probably easier than you think - I just wrap the div/ui update in a function that is called when I have the data.